# How to get true or false without quotes from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have to get data from it in JSON format. I am using a concatenation method as shown below.

```
',"longTimeMember" : "' + CASE WHEN longTimeMember IS NULL THEN '' WHEN 
longTimeMember = 0 THEN 'false' when longTimeMember = 1 THEN 'true' END + '"'
```

Currently, the JSON has either 'false' or 'true' for the longTimeMember value with single quotes around them. Is there a way to have true or false without the quotes so they are true JSON boolean values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding those quotes in yourself, just remove them:

```
',"longTimeMember" : ' + CASE WHEN longTimeMember IS NULL THEN '' WHEN 
longTimeMember = 0 THEN 'false' when longTimeMember = 1 THEN 'true' END
```

Comment: If I do that then I am getting, "Invalid column name 'false'" and "Invalid column name 'true'' errors.

Comment: You can't get rid of the single quotes around the words true/false, just the double-quotation marks you had surrounding the entire CASE statement. I.e., it must be `THEN 'false'`, not `THEN false`. I removed the double-quotes in my example. HTH!

Comment: Hi Russell, sorry I missed it. It works now. Thank you!